# GCE: load balancer health check fails when routing traffic to pods

Tags: load-balancing, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am following the steps at https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-hello-kubernetes and can successfully expose my pod to the outside world with a command like:

```
kubectl expose deployment hello --type="LoadBalancer"
```

I have set up a static IP and when I run

```
$ kubectl get services
NAME         CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP       PORT(S)   AGE
kubernetes   10.111.xxx.x    <none>            443/TCP   13d
hello        10.111.xxx.xx   104.155.xxx.xxx   80/TCP    12d
```

Everything looks OK and works for a couple of days, but after a while the traffic from 104.155.xxx.xxx stops getting routed to my pod and I start getting errors like this when I check the load balancer:

> Instance gke-k8-default-pool-xxxx is unhealthy for 104.155.xxx.xxx

This always happens after a few days. I have no clue what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The load-balancer functionality is provided by the underlying infrastructure(in your case is GCE), so this has barely no relation with kubernetes it self.

> Instance gke-k8-default-pool-xxxx is unhealthy for 104.155.xxx.xxx

From the log you provide, I can only tell the instance(vm) in your GCE can't pass the health check you defined for ip `104.155.xxx.xxx`. So there is several things you need to check:

1. Did anything special happened for instance `gke-k8-default-pool-xxxx`?
2. What health check you defined for `104.155.xxx.xxx` (why would it down for this instance) ?

So you can choose to find out what the true reason above or just restart the instance `gke-k8-default-pool-xxxx` to check if it succeed again.